# Running a queue worker without using cron tasks

Tags: 8, queue

I implemented `hook_queue_info()` with the following code.

```
function ecc_general_queue_info() {
  $queues = array();
  $queues['adding_checklist'] = array(
    'worker callback' => '_ecc_general_apply_queue',
    'time' => 60,
  );
  return $queues;
}
```

I create  items for the queue with the following code.

```
$queue_factory = \Drupal::service('queue');
$queue = $queue_factory->get('adding_checklist');
$queue->createItem([$node, 'insert']);
```

The callback function is the following.

```
function _ecc_general_apply_queue($item) {
  // Some code here.
}
```

I want to run this callback for each item in the queue. How can I process the queue to execute its worker callback for each item?

I don't want to use cron tasks for processing the queue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do because the code sample doesn't give enough context but if you want to execute something when a node is updated you can use hook_entity_update or hook_entity_presave for example

Comment: @wranvaud Sorry if couldn't explain the problem properly.  The issue is actually with queue processing, I want to do some operations using Drupal 8 *Queue API*. I have created the queue, pushed items to it and now don't know how to process it.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for hook_entity_update, this hook is called every time an entity is updated. Try calling your callback function there?

Comment: Getting closer to the solution, thank you @wranvaud. I used the `hook_entity_update` and successfully called my callback function inside of that hook. Now I want to run this callback function by `Queue`, so that I want to run this function for each item in the queue.

Comment: `hook_general_queue_info` doesn't seem to exist. If you need to run your queue not with cron, then you need to code your own way of running the queue. There could be any number of ways to do this, but looking at how cron runs through queues would be a start. There might be some queue runner modules that fit your use case.

Comment: Yes, @mradcliffe is correct: Drupal 8 doesn't use that hook, but an annotation for the class implementing the queue.

Comment: That's `hook_queue_info`, `ecc_general` is my module name.

Comment: No, there is no `hook_queue_info`. Drupal 7 has `hook_cron_queue_info` and Drupal 8 allows you to alter _cron_ QueueWorker plugins with the alter hook `hook_queue_info_alter`. It can be helpful to search for existing core hooks on api.drupal.org

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drupal 8 doesn't use `hook_queue_info()` but annotates the queue class using the [`@QueueWorker`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Annotation%21QueueWorker.php/class/QueueWorker/8.8.x) annotation, as in the following code taken from a Drupal core module.

```
/**
 * Updates a feed's items.
 *
 * @QueueWorker(
 *   id = "aggregator_feeds",
 *   title = @Translation("Aggregator refresh"),
 *   cron = {"time" = 60}
 * )
 */
class AggregatorRefresh extends QueueWorkerBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function processItem($data) {
    if ($data instanceof FeedInterface) {
      $data
        ->refreshItems();
    }
  }

}
```

That, anyway, is **not an annotation for a generic queue**, but for **a queue handled by the [`Cron`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cron.php/class/Cron/8.8.x) class** (which is the class implementing the *cron* service).

If you don't need to handle your queue during cron tasks, you simply don't use the `@QueueWorker` annotation.

The code to consume queue items is similar to the following one. (The code is specific for your case.)

```
$queue = \Drupal::service('queue')->get('adding_checklist');
while ($item = $queue->claimItem()) {
  $node = $item->data[0];
  // ...
  $queue->deleteItem($item);
}
```

Comment: but is not processed in background like cron, right?

Comment: Are you referring to the last snippet I show? It depends from the hook where you put the code, and the meaning you give to _background_. A hook that isn't executed because something I did on a site (for example, a hook invoked during cron tasks) is _background_, for me.

Comment: I mean a background task is like what is done by cron, without staying on current page, invisible to users, but i think drupal cron is the only way to do it (or by external cron in combination with controller and a routing path).

Comment: It is called from the code that invokes `hook_cron()`, but it could be called also from a different function/method, even from a module you wrote.

Comment: In Drupal 9.5.1, you can get queues skipped by cron simply by not providing the `cron` section of the `@QueueWorker` annotation. Queue processing can then be done using `drush queue:run`. The reason for that can be seen in [Drupal\Core\Cron\Cron::processQueues()](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.5.x/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cron.php#L172).

Answer (score 9):

Queue is processed by cron through core. You can also use Drush and Drupal Console to run queue items as well.

Drush:

`drush queue:list` to get the available queues.

`drush queue:run` to run a single item.

`drush queue:delete` to clear a queue.

Drupal Console:

`drupal debug:queue` to debug your queue.

`drupal queue:run <name-of-the-queue>` To run a single item.